# Python struct.unpack from 4 bytes to char

Tags: python, c

I'm trying to connect a C client to a Python server. The C client sends the length of a string and then one by one sends the characters of the string but as bytes.

This is how I send the characters:

```
 for ( i = 0; i<length; i++) {
        ascii = (int)word[i]; --- word is a char []
        ascii = htonl(ascii);
        send(c, &ascii, sizeof(ascii), 0);
    }
```

On the Python side, I use recv and unpack. I figured that I'm getting 4 bytes but I dont know how to convert them to characters with unpack.

```
for i in range (0,nr):
            el = c_socket.recv(4) -- this returns values like  b'\x00\x00\x00a'
            el = struct.unpack("!i",el)[0].decode('ascii') --- this doesn't work

So how do I do that?
```

Comment: Why are you sending the characters as integers — quadrupling the amount of data involved — when you could just send the characters directly as the bytes they are?

Comment: I need the C client to work with  a C server too and that was the only way I could make it work but now I cant make C and Python work together. So is there any way to "decode" the bytes?

Comment: Ok so it works if I just use el.decode('ascii')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`struct.unpack("!i",el)` returns a one-element tuple containing an integer.  To convert this integer to the character at that codepoint, use [`chr`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#chr):

```
el = chr(struct.unpack("!i",el)[0])
```